# Label bounding box in Asymptote

Tags: labels

Here is the code.

```
settings.outformat="pdf";
import graph;

size(4cm, 0cm);
defaultpen(fontsize(16pt) + linewidth(1));

xaxis("$x$", xmin=-1, xmax=1);
yaxis("$y$", ymin=-1, ymax=1);
labelx(0, align=S+W, L=Label(Draw));
```

It produces this:

[image]

The bounding box around the `0` label has different padding values on top and bottom. Is there a way to make it symmetrical?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why the `labelx` is doing that or how to fix it, but you could use a standard `label` command instead.

```
settings.outformat="pdf";
import graph;

size(4cm, 0cm);
defaultpen(fontsize(16pt) + linewidth(1));

xaxis("$x$", xmin=-1, xmax=1);
yaxis("$y$", ymin=-1, ymax=1);
labelx(0, align=S+W, L=Label(Draw));
label("0", (0,0), 2*SE, Draw());
```

[image]

Comment: That was an easy fix :-)